# What is diffrence between Authentication and Middleware at Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

Before i was using codeigniteur after the release of version 4CI i decided to learn laravel 7 now i am in learning stages of laravel 7 master version.

i am little confused and explored alot the documentation of laravel but i not found the solution might be my method of exploring or understanding documentation of laravel is not correct.

i have seen videos on YouTube that made me confused  as some people use

```
php artisan make:auth
```

for creating user authentication but some people use

```
php artisan make:middleware
```

for creation user and some other uses unusall

```
$req->session()->put($user);
```

Now i understand that last method is just manual method for using user authentication but i not understand the diffrence between auth and middleware

Thank you in advance for your explanation

Answer (score 0):

Middlewares allows you to add you to intercept your requests and add logic to them before they are pipelined to Controllers.

In laravel Authentication by default is done using Auth Midddleware.The logic to detect whether the user is logged in is done over here.

There is no limitation that you can only use middleware with relation to authentication only.